# Android activity & import issue

Tags: android, xml

Trying out some android programming that has gone fine up until this point. I'm getting the following errors:

```
Activity cannot be resolved to a type
The import Activity cannot be resolved
```

on the top two imports (activity and bundle) of the following class:

```
package com.example.sqlite;
import android.app.Activity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class Input extends Activity {

    private EditText txtTitle;
    private EditText txtURL;
    private Button btnOK;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.input);

        txtTitle = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        txtURL = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
        btnOK = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);    
    }

}
```

I've done the standard ctrl + shift + O, which does automatically add these imports but the errors remain. I've also rebuilt it over and over with no effect.

Ca anyone see were I'm going wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do right click on the project node in Eclipse and select Android Tools->Fix Project Properties. It looks like you are missing link to your Android libraries. Good way to check on that is to open properties-> Java build path -> Libraries and verify that Android link is there. If not - do Properties->Android and select project target you would like to use

Comment: Hi Bostone. I just tried the project node android tools, then fix project properties, and nothing happens?

Comment: Also, i checked the libraries and I have Android 2.2 and Android Dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

You may occasionally see strange erros if any of your XML files fail to build. Check your console to see if any of your layout or resources have errors. Do the following:

`Project > Clean`

If this does not fix it, verify that pour souce actually exists in the project path:

`com.example.sqlite`

Answer (score 0):

Check your manifest xml if the activity is included.. This can sometimes cause the error.

Comment: This would *in most cases* cause a runtime error, not a compile error.

Comment: Ok so after about 97 refreshes and cleans. Then a project shutdown and reload, i have the imports. Ty all